# Prove that if two stochastic processes are modifications of each other they have they have the same finite dimensional law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I would like to prove that if I consider $X$ and $Y$ two stochastic processes which are modifications of each other, then they have same finite dimensional law.

Here is my attempt : We know that for all $t\in [0,T]$ we have $X_t=Y_t$ almost surely. Consider $0
\leq t_1<…<t_n\leq T$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It comes
$$
\mathbb{P}_{X_{t_1},…X_{t_n}}(B) = \mathbb{P}(\left\{ \omega : X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i \quad \forall i\in [1, n]\cap\mathbb{N} \right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\})
$$

Then I remark that

$$
\mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) \neq Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + 0 = \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) \neq Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega : Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\})
$$

And at this point I would like to use this to conclude but I do not see how so  I am wondering if it is correct. Do not hesitate to sharpe your hints or remarks please.

Thank you !

### New attempt

$$  
\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}) =\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ X_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) \neq Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + 0 = \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) = Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) + \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) \neq Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) = \mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\})
$$

Using the fact that $\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}(\left\{ Y_{t_i}(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\cap\left\{\omega : X_{t_i}(\omega) \neq Y_{t_i}(\omega)\right\}) = 0$.

Thanks to Michael I have seen an error on the way my events were written. Here is the correction

$$
\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{X_{t_i}\in B_i\right\} = \cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{X_{t_i}\in B_i\right\}\cap\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{Y_{t_i}=X_{t_i}\right\}\cup\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{X_{t_i}\in B_i\right\}\cap \cup_{i=1}^{n} \left\{Y_{t_i}\neq X_{t_i}\right\}
$$

And by notice that

$$
\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{X_{t_i}\in B_i\right\}\cap \cup_{i=1}^{n} \left\{Y_{t_i}\neq X_{t_i}\right\}) = 0
$$

Since $\cap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{X_{t_i}\in B_i\right\}\cap \cup_{i=1}^{n} \left\{Y_{t_i}\neq X_{t_i}\right\}\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} \left\{Y_{t_i}\neq X_{t_i}\right\}$ which is of measure $0$.

We can conclude using the same trick as above

Comment: A countable intersection of almost sure sets is almost sure. Therefore $(X_{t_1},\cdots,X_{t_n})=(Y_{t_1},\cdots,Y_{t_n})$ almost surely.

Comment: @Will Thank you for your comment ! I have edited my post trying to use your hint. Let me know if it was not what you have in mind

Comment: You have the right idea, but your complements are not precise. I would define $C=\cap_{i=1}^n\{X_i=Y_i\}$, note that $P[C]=1$, then you can condition on $C$ and $C^c$. I see you are trying to do that, but negating each event in an intersection does not form a complement of that intersection. Rather, by DeMorgan's law we have $$(\cap_{i=1}^nA_i)^c = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c$$ You can also use DeMorgan's law (and the union bound) to prove the fact Will mentions.

Comment: @Michael Thank you a lot I think I have understood the point you mentionned. I have updated thé post.